# Implement Section ListView with Checkbox?

Tags: java, android, listview

I need section `Listview` with checkbox and every row have some have I need total of selected row. Here I have used `Recyclerview` due to Lazy Loading I have to used `Listview`.
[image]

List view have 10 member in Array List but initially i am getting only 4 row value i need 10 at initially.This happen due to Lazy Loading.

Thanks's in advance

Comment: Please add some more details

Comment: does you need sticky section header or not

Comment: Just fyi lazy loading can be implemented using RecyclerView as well

Comment: Is lazyLoading available in ListView?

Answer (score 4):

You can implement a Custom interface in your Adapter. When you checked your item from list you have to pass the result to your Activity and later you can make sum of it.

```
interface CheckItemList{

        public void onCheckItem(int value){}

    }
```

> In your Adapter Class create a reference of Interface and call onCheckItem()

```
CheckItemList checkItemList = (CheckItemList) mContext;

satView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
              if(isChecked){
       checkItemList.onCheckItem(value);
         }
       }
   }
);
```

Implement CheckItemList interface in your activity or some singleton class.

```
class MyActivity extends Activity implements CheckItemList.
  onCheckItem(int value){
  //Add your code to store checked value  
}
```

}